# Why doesn't perfect forwarding (catch-all) work to implement a copy-assignment?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, copy-assignment

In a class with a series of ctors (most of which have exactly one argument), I want all one-argument ctors to also be mirrored by a corresponding assignment operator. The ctors include, but are not limited to a copy-ctor and a move-ctor. So this, should satisfy the rule-of-five.

```
  template <typename T>
  object& operator=(T&& from) {
    // ...
    return *this;
  }
```

Here is a minimal example: https://ideone.com/OKprcr (thanks to @Daniel H for pointing out constness).

The error I get is

```
error: object of type 'object' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
...
note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because 'object' has a user-declared move constructor
```

Why doesn't the function template implement the copy-assignment operator?

Comment: Hard to tell without a [MCVE]. Does `object` have any non-copyable data member?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yes, it has an `std::unique_ptr` pimpl, but that's why I am implementing a custom copy-assignment. Maybe that's why I couldn't create a minimal example. I'll check.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. https://ideone.com/KM4NMD

Comment: @bitmask A minimal example doesn’t mean an example that *compiles*, it means an example which *shows the same issue*. In your case a minimal verifiable example would be code that we could plug into a compiler to get the same error message.

Comment: I realise that. The problem is, whenever I rip the problem out, it suddenly compiles fine.

Comment: @bitmask Of course it compiles fine when you rip out the part which doesn’t compile. You should include a minimal example which *shows this compiler error* in the question.

Comment: @DanielH Look, I'm taking the part that should reproduce the problem (see ideone) but outside my project it does not trigger the error, (no idea why) while I get a problem inside my project for missing a copy-assignment.

Comment: @bitmask Oh, I misread what you were saying.

Comment: My *guess* is that it’s `const`-related. If I make `p` into a `const object` in your example, [it fails](https://godbolt.org/g/sRdth2). Try making the assignment operator take in a `T const&&`. Also, you should check for self-assignment and self-move, as your code gives UB in those cases.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. However, adding `const` to the argument (either `T const&` or `T const&&`) doesn't appear to change anything.

Comment: Added a MCVe @VittorioRomeo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the function template implement the copy-assignment operator?

Because the standard says so ([class.copy.assign]/1):

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static **non-template** member function of
>   class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

Note there's no `X&&` in there either.